# Data won't load in Angular view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view

So I'm working through an AngularJS tutorial, so I know this is not the best way to complete these tasks, but this is the step I'm on. I'm trying to load data into a view, but the data doesn't display. My ng-view and my ng-route is working properly to get me there, but once I'm on patient.html, I just have my table headers, and no info. What am I missing?

Here is my module

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module('cbApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',{
                controller  : 'MainCtrl',
                templateUrl : 'views/main.html' 
            })
            .when('/patient/:roomId', {
                controller  : 'PatientCtrl',
                templateUrl : 'views/patient.html'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo : '/' });
    });

}());
```

Here is my controller

```
(function() {
    var PatientCtrl = function ($scope, $routeParams) {      

        var roomId = $routeParams.roomId;
        $scope.patient = null;

        //create a function that searches the rooms for id
        function init() {
            var length = $scope.rooms.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
                if ($scope.rooms[i].name === parseInt(roomId)) {
                    $scope.patient = $scope.rooms[i].patient;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        $scope.rooms = [
                        { id : 101, name : "101", patient : { id : 1, last: "Ratcliff", first : "Daniel"} },
                        { id : 102, name : "102", patient : { id : 2, last: "Gibson", first : "Mel"} },
                        { id : 103, name : "103", patient : { id : 3, last: "Fey", first : "Tina"} }
                    ]; 
        init();

    }
    //handle DI to avoid minification errors
    PatientCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams'];
    //define the controller in angular
    angular.module('cbApp').controller('PatientCtrl', PatientCtrl);
}());
```

and my view

```
<h2>Room Details</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="pt in patient">
        <td>{{ pt.first }}</td>
        <td>{{ pt.last }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you get any error in console?

Comment: If you put a console.log($scope.patient) after the for loop, do you see the correct result in the console?

Comment: @NishamMahsin nope. no errors.

Comment: @Cognitronic Yes. The correct object shows up in the console.

Comment: @can u make a fiddle or plunker

Comment: @NishamMahsin Yes. But not until later tonight. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @NishamMahsin Here is a plunk, but nothing is working here. :( http://plnkr.co/edit/uTvSeQ7sryou40Z0SYCC?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completed your plunker for you .

But not sure if this is what u want achieve.

here you can see it:

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GyhVMngm5MR2y5oUMaUH?p=preview)

```
<tr >
        <td>{{ patient.first }}</td>
        <td>{{ patient.last }}</td>
</tr>
```

plus some links and path

Comment: So, was it because I was trying to ng-repeat something that had nothing to repeat?

Comment: some pathes in the plunker wasnt correct . if ($scope.rooms[i].name == roomId) { $scope.patient = $scope.rooms[i].patient;  break; }     gives you the patient corresponding to the $routeParams . after that u have one result for your detail

Answer (score 1):

You very carefully converted the roomId parameter to an int, and then triple-equal compare it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working plunker of your code....with slight modifications:
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6AOzZlKZ2RafLrjv5aKY?p=preview)

```
    angular.module('cbApp', ['ngRoute']).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
       //configure your routes
    });
(function() {
    var PatientCtrl = function ($scope, $routeParams) {      

        var roomId = $routeParams.roomId || 101;
        $scope.patients = [];

        //create a function that searches the rooms for id
        function init() {
            var length = $scope.rooms.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
                if (parseInt($scope.rooms[i].name) === parseInt(roomId)) {
                    $scope.patients.push($scope.rooms[i].patient);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        $scope.rooms = [
                        { id : 101, name : "101", patient : { id : 1, last: "Ratcliff", first : "Daniel"} },
                        { id : 102, name : "102", patient : { id : 2, last: "Gibson", first : "Mel"} },
                        { id : 103, name : "103", patient : { id : 3, last: "Fey", first : "Tina"} }
                    ]; 
        init();

    }
    //define the controller in angular
    angular.module('cbApp').controller('PatientCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', PatientCtrl]);
}());
```